# Alter behavior of Next Page > button on a multipage webform page

Tags: webforms

In a multipage webform (the webform module), there is the Next Page > button. It has 2 handlers,

```
webform_client_form_pages
webform_client_form_submit
```

How do I add another one? This is because I want to change the behavior of the Next Page > button. It's behavior should depend on the value of a checkbox on the page. Or should I have to do it in another way?

Thanks,

Eric J.

Answer (score 0):

`webform_client_form_submit` handler should be enough to use. Depends what the *'behavior'* exactly is.